# Multiple Check Boxes in form to return Array, but returning 0 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form and i am trying to submit a list of languages spoken via check boxes, that will be submitted as an Array, serialised in the controler and saved to DB.

According to the docs, I should be able to use

```
<%= f.check_box :languages, {multiple: true}, "EN", nil %>
<%= f.check_box :languages, {multiple: true}, "ES", nil %>
<%= f.check_box :languages, {multiple: true}, "US", nil %>
```

Which gives the HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="EN" name="service[languages][]" id="service_languages_en">
 <input type="checkbox" value="ES" name="service[languages][]" id="service_languages_es">
 <input type="checkbox" value="US" name="service[languages][]" id="service_languages_us">
```

in controller

```
params.require(:service).permit(..., :languages => [])
```

But in my logs all i get from the params is  `"languages"=>"0",`

Im sure its something obvious im missing, so any help would be massively appreciated!

I know it could (and probably should) be done with has_many association, but I have reasons for wanting to do it this way for now.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure where `{multiple: true}` comes into it either. I don't see any mention of that in the docs. Check the actual HTML output because I don't think what you've put there is actually what's being output. There should be two inputs per call to `check_box`.

Comment: that HTML is from the output, from my browser, which i s why i though it would work. Just having a try with your other answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs state:

> It's intended that method returns an integer and if that integer is above zero, then the checkbox is checked.

You might want to take a look at `collection_check_boxes` instead:

```
f.collection_check_boxes :languages, {'EN': 'EN', 'ES': 'ES', 'US': 'US'}, :key, :value
```

I haven't run that code, and it'd be good to be able to remove the repetition in the hash, but it expects an object that it can call methods on I think.

Comment: gant get this to work, keeps coming back to `undefined method `key' for [:EN, "EN"]:Array`

Comment: Try `f.collection_check_boxes :languages, ['EN', 'ES', 'US'], :to_s, :to_s` and let me know :)

Comment: This did work, thank you, Although in the end I had to go with has_many and another table, which was the proper way anyway I guess! But learned something new! :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexHickinbotham :) I'm glad it worked for you, and that you found another way around it in the end. There's no problem with not using another table, especially when the options don't change much (can be stored in a constant in your model instead).